# Find multiple strings between two arguments

Tags: go, kubernetes

I'm trying to make a function that will get a string between two arguments (*rewrite* and *redirect*). I can't wrap my head around it.

I have a string that looks like this:

```
add_header X-Robots-Tag "noindex, follow" always; rewrite ^/en/about/Administration/index.aspx /en/about/more-about/administration redirect; rewrite ^/en/about/Administration/supervisory-board/index.aspx /nl/over/meer-over/administration redirect; rewrite ^/en/about/Departments-sections-and-fields/index.aspx /en/about/more-about/department-divisions-and-fields redirect; rewrite ^/en/about/For-companies/index.aspx /en/about/more-about/for-companies redirect; rewrite ^/en/about/contact-information/index.aspx /en/about/more-about/contact-information redirect; rewrite ^/en/about/index.aspx /nl/over redirect;
```

And I want the following output:

```
/en/about/Administration/index.aspx /en/about/more-about/administration
 
/en/about/Administration/supervisory-board/index.aspx /nl/over/meer-over/administration 

/en/about/Departments-sections-and-fields/index.aspx /en/about/more-about/department-divisions-and-fields  

/en/about/For-companies/index.aspx /en/about/more-about/for-companies

/en/about/contact-information/index.aspx /en/about/more-about/contact-information

/en/about/index.aspx /nl/over
```

What is the proper regex or method to get all strings between the two arguments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
\brewrite \^(.*?)\s+redirect;
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/sVR4Ey/1)

---

- `\brewrite \^` - literally 'rewrite' between a word-boundary on the left and a space followed by literal '^' on the right;
- `(.*?)` - Match (lazy) 0+ characters;
- `\s+redirect;` - Literally 'redirect' between 1+ whitespace characters on the left and a semi-colon on the right.

---

See an online GO [demo](https://go.dev/play/p/fjIIEijmCd4) which will print:

```
/en/about/Administration/index.aspx /en/about/more-about/administration
/en/about/Administration/supervisory-board/index.aspx /nl/over/meer-over/administration
/en/about/Departments-sections-and-fields/index.aspx /en/about/more-about/department-divisions-and-fields
/en/about/For-companies/index.aspx /en/about/more-about/for-companies
/en/about/contact-information/index.aspx /en/about/more-about/contact-information
/en/about/index.aspx /nl/over
```